# How to make a responsive div in css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have this small webpage I am trying to build. Everything looks good til I try to scale-in and out the browser windows to check it's responsiveness.

It looks good with 320x568 as below.

[image]

But when it scaled in (reduce the browser window, it shows like this, which I don't want that black box (`.transbox) to go down beyond the photo.)

[image]

I am using bootstrap framework and I **DON'T NEED TO USE** `css` media queries to make it responsive.

How can I do it with `css` instead?

This is my current html and css

```css
.masthead {
  height: 20vh;
  min-height: 370px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.transbox {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  min-height: 300px;
}

div.transbox p {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.transbox h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header className="masthead">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row align-items-center">
      <div className="col-12 text-center">
        <div class="transbox">
          <h1 className="font-weight-light">
            All your Escort needs within a single place!
          </h1>
          <p className="lead">
            Find the best set of escort services in Sri Lanka
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Can someone please help me? Is there a bootstrap class or pure css way to do this?

Comment: and do you want to keep the `height: 20vh`?

Comment: yes I do want to keep the height as `20vh` @NirBerko.

Comment: @Manjuboyz I tried `display: flex` and it changed the texts. They are going side by side. Which is not what I want.

Comment: how is you margin defined around that dark box? If it's something like`class="m-4"` then you could swap it with `class="m-4"` `class="m-1 m-sm-4"`

Comment: How I have defined the margin can be seen in the question. I have added my `css` part too. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @ToRrent you should use `minmax()` for the font size, and also thinking about reduce the padding (because there is no magical way you can keep the font size and the pending and also the max height of 20vh)

Comment: I mean, by using the `minmax()` you can make the font size responsive

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example:

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.masthead {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

div.transbox {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  min-height: 300px;
}

div.transbox p {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.transbox h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <div class="transbox">
          <h1 class="font-weight-light">
            All your Escort needs within a single place!
          </h1>
          <p class="lead">
            Find the best set of escort services in Sri Lanka
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.masthead {
  height: 20vh;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.transbox {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  min-height: 300px;
}

div.transbox p {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.transbox h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header className="masthead">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row align-items-center">
      <div className="col-12 text-center">
        <div class="transbox">
          <h1 className="font-weight-light">
            All your Escort needs within a single place!
          </h1>
          <p className="lead">
            Find the best set of escort services in Sri Lanka
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Your content is more as compare to width of background image. So, just increase the height of your background image **or just reduce the font-size via media query.**

Comment: Is it possible to adapt the font-size with css? a responsive font size?

Comment: Adapting font-size with CSS is definitely doable. 
For this, you'll need to use the relative units. 
For example, a way to increase/decrease the font size with the viewport width is font-size: calc(16px + 1vw).